# Auto resize text in UITextView for fit all devices

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, autolayout, uitextview

I am trying to resize text in `UITextView` to resize and fit the `margins` but right now its all condensed on the left side. It's working perfect on the iPhones but not the iPads. I'm using `autoLayout` in the `storyboard`. How can i achieve this. [image]

Comment: Sometimes it shows like this in storyboard but please run and then check actual result

Comment: @HardikShah its shows like that on the actual device aswell

Comment: Have you tried making the horizontal content hugging priority Required (1000)?

Comment: Are you able to provide the part isolated project? because the text doesn't seem right.

Comment: @IOSDealBreaker yes

Comment: Are you sure there are not hard breaks in that text?  It looks like the constraints are correct but the lines aren't wrapping because someone put a hard return at the end of each line.

Comment: @JoshHomann i'm using attributed text. Thats the only way i could do it